# get_queryset() from a js text input

Tags: javascript, django

In this step I'm trying to avoid making a form to send data over to django from the frontend.
Ideally I would like to pass a simple string to the queryset with an onclick button, so I can make the tag filters on my Post model and show the ones with the tags from the string input. (just send the string to the queryset, I can deal with the split() and strip() to make it valid)

The simplified html would be something like

```
<input type="text" name="tag_filter">
<button type="button" onclick="Tag_Filter()">Filter</button>

<script>

  function Tag_Filter() {
    var tags;
    tags = document.getElementById("tag_filter");
  }

</script>
```

And the ListView

```
class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post #.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["black&white", "red"]).distinct()
template_name = 'post/home.html'    # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
#queryset = Post.objects.all()
context_object_name = 'posts'
#ordering = ['-date_posted']

def get_queryset(self):
    tag_list = #the return from the Tag_Filter() js
    return Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tag_list).annotate(num_tags=Count('tags')).filter(num_tags__gte=len(tag_list)).order_by('-date_posted').distinct()
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='post-home'),
other_paths()
]
```

Comment: in this i suggest use ajax, send your data(filter) to url this url call to def search(request):........... and this get the query and return by JsonResponse to ajax...

Comment: Most of the documentation and solutions I've read online suggest using ajax, but I haven't worked with it previously so I don't know how exactly implement it in this case

Comment: ok i'm write a answer with an example for you..!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use ajax, then your first step is implement ajax ...ajax is from Jquery then you need include the jquery on your template only for one file html or if your prefer in your base.html on the end of file before from your body end tag:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="{% static 'Jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
....
...
all my files js
....
</body>
</html>
```

for download this jquery.min.js , please go to this link and save the file in to folder: static/Jquery/:

[Link for download Jquery min.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js)

Don't forget save as  **jquery.min.js**

The next is setup your settings.py for accept the static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
]
```

the next is put the tag for load static files on the top of your  file html or base.html as you wish:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
...
...
 <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="{% static 'Jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
....
...
all my files js
....
</body>
</html>
```

ok, now we include **$.ajax** first you need include on your button a function that recive your value from your input:

```
<input type="text" name="tag_filter" id ="tag_filter">
<button type="button" onclick="tag_filter()">Filter</button>
```

now your function tag_filter:

```
   function getCookie(name) {
      
      var cookieValue = null;
      if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
          var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
          for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
              // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
              cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
      //RETURN YOUR TOKEN FROM DJANGO FOR SEND FROM AJAX
      return cookieValue;

    }//end function getCookie

function tag_filter(){
   var tag_filter = $("#tag_filter").val();
   if(tag_filter == '' || tag_filter == null){
     alert('write yout filter for search !!');
     return false;
   }
   //now we include the ajax call
       //token
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "search_filter",
            data:{
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken, 
                tag_filter:tag_filter,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                code = data.result;
                if(code=='ok_select'){
                 // here write you code for the success answer from ajax call
                 console.log(data);
                }
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
           
             alert('Error ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        

            }//end error
        }); 
}
```

now you need create a def for search with the parameter example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse

    ...
    ..
    def SearchFilter(request):
    filter = request.GET['tag_filter']
    ....
    ....
    data ={
    'result':'ok_select'
    'data': #your query
    }
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

now you need declare this def on yours urls.py example:

```
from myapp.views import SearchFilter
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^search_filter', SearchFilter, name='search_filter'),
...
...
]
```

this is all... on the case of ajax this return success answer by console check this answer on the console from your web browser favorite..

and good luck..!!

Comment: I'm working with class-based views, there's the main problem I'm having because I don't really know how the request is handled by the ListView class I'm inheriting from.
I can't find a way to make the:
    filter = request.GET['tag_filter'] and get the dictionary from the JSON

Everything you wrote helped though